# Premature Deletion

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions, proposal

A while ago a question was deleted for which I had spent quite a while doing the research to answer it correctly. The reason for its deletion appears to be that most people didn't think enough information was present in the question. There was not; but it was still possible to give the case in which the answer to a question within the question was true. The Author wanted to know why this was the case.

Link to Question: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079036/if-Γ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079036/if-%CE%93)

The question was as follows:
If A ⊨ B and C ⊨ B, then A ∩ C ⊨ B is false? Why? Propositional logic

My Answer:
The third statement would only be false for the case in which the set of interpretations that make all members of A true does not have an intersection with the set of interpretations that makes all members of B true.

Giving the answer to the cases in which the statement in question was false would have allowed the author to look more closely at his/her text and perhaps edit/answer the question.

Because the question was updated almost directly after the first few comments we can observe that the Author was furiously re-reading the text and thinking of ways to re-write the question. This all happened while the question was reviving down-votes: which must have felt rather bad for the Author.

I believe the question was closed prematurely. Either by the Author or by some auto-delete function of the site that I am not aware of.

In principal, I do not believe questions should be closed or criticized before the Author of them has had time to update the question based on feedback they receive in the comments.

I would also like to link here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/320/how-should-we-deal-with-ill-founded-questions

For the comment made by Akhil Mathew:

> Blockquote
>   I'd say answering in the comments is best. If the question was well-thought out and well-written, I'm sympathetic; in this case, since there is no motivation for the question, my inclination is to close it.

I agree with Mathew's comment; however one should note that not everyone has the privilege to answer in comments; which might allow people to clarify certain points in the question and perhaps direct them to a better one. Those that do not have this privilege run the risk of losing what little rep they have with a bad answer; which results in long research times to ensure what they say is clear and not false. In my case the time I took to do this exceed the life of the question.

I propose that questions should not be deleted by a party other than the Author within a certain time frame of creation particularly if the question has been edited or is still been edited.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you also added a link to the question. (You might have it in your browser history.) I do not see such question among [recently deleted questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last2days) - which suggests that it might have been self-deletion. (Self-deleted questions are not shown in that list.)

Comment: Just added it then. Thanks for the tip

Comment: You've tagged this as discussion, but your last paragraph is for a feature proposal. I'll respond to the feature proposal. Right now, an author cannot delete their question if they would also be deleting others' upvoted (or accepted) content. On the other hand, authors can delete their questions otherwise. Frequently authors realize a mistake in their question, or find a solution elsewhere, or want to delete their question for some other reason --- I don't see a good reason to take these abilities away before an answer appears, and the current system has worked very well for a long time.

Comment: I was unaware at the time there was a proposal tag. I was also unaware at the time of the post that the Author had removed it and not someone else/an automatic feature.

What I meant by the proposal is that other people should not be able to delete it after a certain time frame for which it has been edited or created. I'll make this more clear in a edit.

Comment: If you read the faq item called [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221#5222), you will find out that a question can be deleted by other users only after it has been closed (put on hold). After closing, it is still necessary to wait at least *48 hours*, unless the question has *score -3 or lower*.

Comment: BTW @mixedmath was probably referring to the tag ([meta-tag:feature-request]) rather than ([meta-tag:proposal]). But if you indeed want to make a feature request, you should probably make it clear how your suggestion differs from the way the system currently works.

Comment: @MartinSleziak the particular question linked was self-deleted by the OP

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I know that. (And so does the OP now. The OP writes in a comment (emphasis mine): "I was also unaware at the time of the post *that the Author had removed it* ... by the proposal is that *other people* should not be able to delete...") Of course it's op to the OP to clarify, but to me it seems that the proposed feature request is not about self-deletions. (Although it was probably prompted by one.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I see what you mean. I don't usually read much of a question here after realizing it is for a site change that will never happen; might be better if I read a little more when feeling the urge to comment.